# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') error JWT(Json Web Token)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

**Created MongoDb User Schema**

[MongoDb User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHXAp.png)

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); // Import mongoose

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema( // Create User Schema
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }, 
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },  
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: {  
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }    // Add timestamps
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);  // Export User Model
```

**Used express.js Routes files in user.js**

[user.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puiNj.png)

```js
const User = require("../models/User"); // Import User Model Schema
const { 
  verifyTokenAndAuthorization 
} = require("./verifyToken"); // Import verifyTokenAndAuthorization
const router = require("express").Router();   // Import express Router
//UPDATE
router.put("/:id", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.password) {
    req.body.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(   // Encrypt password
      req.body.password,                    // Password
      process.env.PASS_SEC    // Encrypt password with secret key
    ).toString();
  }

  try {
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(   // Find user by id and update
      req.params.id,  // Find user by id
      {
        $set: req.body,   // Set user data
      },
      { new: true }  // Return updated user
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedUser);  // Return user
  } catch (err) { // Catch error
    res.status(500).json(err);  // Return error
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Routes files in auth.js added access token**

[Access Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6oUl.png)

```js
const router = require('express').Router(); // import express
const User = require('../models/User'); // import user model
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js'); // import crypto-js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // import jsonwebtoken


//REGİSTER
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,    // username
        email: req.body.email,  // req.body.email is the same as req.body.email
        password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(req.body.password,process.env.PAS_SEC).toString(),   // encrypt password
    })  // create new user
    try{
        const savedUser = await newUser.save(); // save user
        res.status(201).json(savedUser);            // send user
    } catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({message: err});   // send error
    } 
});

//LOGIN

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username}); // find user

        if(!user){  // if user is not found
            return res.status(400).json({message: "User not found"}); // send error
        }

        const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password,process.env.PAS_SEC); // decrypt password

        const Originalpassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); // convert to string

        const {password,...others}  = user._doc; // others is the user data without password // Güvenlik için password olmadan kullanıcıyı aktardık ve ._doc ise mongodb datamızı document içinden gösteriyor
                                                    
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ // create access token
            userId: user._id,   // user id  
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin   // isAdmin
        },
        process.env.JWT_SEC,    // secret key           
        {expiresIn: "24h"}   // expire time
        ); 

        if(Originalpassword !== req.body.password){ // if password is not correct
            return res.status(401).json({message: "Incorrect password"}); // send error
        } else{
            res.status(200).json({...others,accessToken}); // send success
        }
 
    }catch(err){    // if error
        res.status(500).json({message: err});   // send error
    }
});

module.exports = router; // export router
```

**Routes files in verifyToken.js**

[VerifyToken.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DB33.png)

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");  // Import jsonwebtoken
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => { // Verify token
  const authHeader = req.headers.token; // Get token from header
  if (authHeader) { // If token exists
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1]; // Get token from header
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SEC, (err, user) => { // Verify token
      if (err) res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!"); // Return error
      req.user = user;  // Set user
      next(); // Call next middleware
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json("You are not authenticated!");  // Return error
  }
};

const verifyTokenAndAuthorization = (req, res, next) => { // Verify token and authorization
  verifyToken(req, res, () => {
    if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {  // If user id is equal to id from url or user is admin
      next(); // Call next middleware
    } else {
      res.status(403).json("You are not alowed to do that!"); // Return error
    }
  });
};

module.exports = {
  verifyToken,  // Export verifyToken 
  verifyTokenAndAuthorization,    // Export verifyTokenAndAuthorization
};
```

I used Postman. All the queries are working, but when I want to update the user, postman also gives an error. How can ı fix this error is : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') error. i cant see where i went wrong pls hep mee

[Postman Error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Mpo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the JWT token that you get in the response of your login call to the request to update the user.